# Codio Guide Throbber: Is there an open source jQuery version?

Tags: javascript, jquery, codio

[Codio](http://codio.com) has a cool feature which I think is called Guide Throbber. When you log in for the first time you'll see various throbbing buttons around the page which act as 'help hints'. Clicking one of these buttons shows a popover that contains help text. Once a throbber has been clicked, it never shows again.

To the best of my knowledge, this feature is proprietary to Codio. Is there an open source jQuery or JavaScript version available?

Answer (score 0):

I actually wrote the code for the throbber on Codio, and yes it is proprietary code, but there is no reason why we couldn't open source that, but no idea when I would get the time ;)

I don't know of any open source libs that can do this.

Comment: I really like it. On my personal site, I've been using LinkedIn's [Hopscotch Tour](http://github.com/linkedin/hopscotch) to provide help hints but the throbber is a far more unobtrusive way of doing it. The tour approach 'whizzes' the user around the screen which can be quite offputting to some users. I've noticed [Disqus](http://disqus.com/websites/) also use a throbber.